# How to convert data types to readable string

Tags: python, string, types

I was wondering because I haven't found a working answer to convert data types to readable format.

Comment: Define "readable" or do you just want to convert any type to a string? If so then `str(...)` is probably enough.

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at adding **str** and **repr** methods to your data types.

[**str**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

> Called by the str() built-in function and by the print statement to
>   compute the "informal" string representation of an object.

[**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

> Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions
>   (reverse quotes) to compute the "official" string representation of an
>   object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python
>   expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same
>   value (given an appropriate environment).

By example:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacturer+" "+self.model
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{"manufacturer": "'+self.manufacturer+'", "model": "'+self.model+'"}'

c = Car("Ford", "Focus")
print str(c)
> "Ford Focus"
print repr(c)
> {"manufacturer": "Ford", "model": "Focus"}
```